# Username input field covered by yellow when google auto-completes (Bootstrap 4.1)?

Tags: html, autocomplete, bootstrap-4

I have an email field for logging in, and it works just fine when the user types in the field. However when google auto-completes the field, it fills over with a yellow layer like so:

[image]

Here is the code for the email field:

```
<label>Email address</label>
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="">
```

I am using Bootstrap 4.1 - any ideas why it does this?

Comment: To tell the user that this field was *filled automatically*, This is not a bootstrap problem, It's a browser feature

Comment: That's not about bootstrap, it's native chrome behavior to tell that field was autocompleted. As far as I know there is no way to override it using `<input>`

Comment: How would you recomend telling the user it was auto completed?